# Using MongoDB $out aggregation operator in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Does anybody know how one would go about using the $out operator to push the results of a MongoDB aggregation function into a new collection in node.js?

This is what I have:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;

var createGroups = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('people').aggregate(
     [
       { $group: { "_id": "$code", "sendees" : {$push : "$email"}, "count": { $sum: 1 } } }

     ]
   ).toArray(function(err, result) {
     assert.equal(err, null);
     console.log(result);
     callback(result);

   });
};

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:12121/systest', function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  createGroups(db, function() {
      db.close();
  });
});
```

Which outputs to the console fine, exactly as I'd expect - but I'm having little luck trying to export this to a new collection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to supply `$out` in your aggregation. See the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

So your code should look like:

```
 db.collection('people').aggregate(
     [
       { 
         $group: {
           "_id": "$code", 
           "sendees" : {$push : "$email"}, 
           "count": { $sum: 1 } 
          } 
        },
        {
          $out: "collection name"
        }
     ]
   )
```

Comment: I discovered that while `$out` does seem to work, there is also an `out` parameter you can supply to the Node.js driver's `aggregate()` function, see https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate .. so, `db.collection(name).aggregate([ ..pipeline.. ], { out: 'collection name' }), seems to work for me, though I did find with both approaches the aggregate would seem to lock up if I didn't provide a callback function in the third argument, or handle `on('data', ..')` and `on('end', ..)` on the `AggregationCursor` returned from `aggregate()`.

Comment: Be aware that `$out` doesn't take effect until some kind of I/O on the cursor (e.g. `toArray`) is requested, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49835278/3746543 That wasn't a problem in this case, but maybe this note saves others from wondering why the heck it doesn't work for them...

Answer (score 0):

You could try use the **[mongo-aggregate-out](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-aggregate-out)** package which saves aggregation results to a collection for Mongo versions < 2.6. If your MongoDB version is 2.6 or newer, the module would behave as passthrough and will use the native feature:

```
var aggregateOut = require('mongo-aggregate-out'),
    pipelineArray = [
       { 
           $group: { 
               "_id": "$code", 
               "sendees" : {$push : "$email"}, 
               "count": { $sum: 1 } 
           } 
       }
    ];

var createGroups = function(db, callback) {
    aggregateOut(db.collection('people'), pipelineArray, { out: "newCollection"}, 
        function (err) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            var cur = db.collection('newCollection').find();
            callback(cur);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers folks - both very helpful. As it happens I was using an outdated version of mongo from before $out came into being - but once I sorted this out and did as you suggested above it worked perfectly.