# Mongodb node.js $out with aggregation only working if calling toArray()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Saving an aggregation query using `"mongodb": "^3.0.6"` as result with the `$out` operator is only working when calling `.toArray()`.

The aggregation step(s):

```
let aggregationSteps = [{
    $group: {
        _id: '$created_at',
    }
}, {'$out': 'ProjectsByCreated'}];
```

Executing the aggregation:

`await collection.aggregate(aggregationSteps, {'allowDiskUse': true})`

Expected result: New collection called *ProjectsByCreated*.

Result: No collection, query does not throw an exception but is not being executed? (takes only 1ms)

Appending `toArray()` results in the expected behaviour:

`await collection.aggregate(aggregationSteps, {'allowDiskUse': true}).toArray();`

Why does mongodb only create the result collection when calling `.toArray()` and where does the documentation tell so? How can I fix this?

The documentation doesn't seem to provide any information about this:

- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html

Comment: Very good question. It sounds like the aggregation is returning a cursor, and until you iterate through the cursor (e.g. using the `.toArray()` addition) the aggregation is not written out to the ProjectsByCreated collection. That sounds very unhelpful! Have you investigated what happens if you try [other cursor methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html)?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Manually iterating the cursor - pseudo code: `while(cursor.hasNext())` produces an output collection - just closing the cursor doesn't work either.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MongoDB acknowledge this behaviour, but they also say this is working as designed.

It has been logged as a bug in the MongoDB JIRA, [$out aggregation stage doesn't take effect](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1398), and the responses say it is not a fault:

> This behavior is intentional and has not changed in some time with the node driver. When you "run" an aggregation by calling Collection.prototype.aggregate, we create an intermediary Cursor which is not executed until some sort of I/O is requested. This allows us to provide the chainable cursor API (e.g. cursor.limit(..).sort(..).project(..)), building up the find or aggregate options in a builder before executing the initial query.
>
> *... Chaining toArray in order to execute the out stage doesn't feel quite right. Is there something more natural that I haven't noticed?*
>
> Unfortunately not, the chained out method there simply continues to build your aggregation. Any of the following methods will cause the initial aggregation to be run: toArray, each, forEach, hasNext, next. We had considered adding something like exec/run for something like change streams, however it's still in our backlog. For now you could theoretically just call hasNext which should run the first aggregation and retrieve the first batch (this is likely what exec/run would do internally anyway).

So, it looks like you do have to call one of the methods to start iterating the cursor before `$out` will do anything. Adding `.toArray()`, as you're already doing, is probably safest. Note that `to.Array()` does not load the entire result into RAM as normal; because it includes a `$out`, [the aggregation returns an empty cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate).

Comment: I still feel like it should automatically create the collection. I will use the `.toArray()` function - thanks :)

Comment: I'm with you there. That is why I wondered if anybody else agreed with us and had reported it as a bug to MongoDB themselves. I'm sure the underlying reasons for that design choice make sense technically, but the behaviour is still frustratingly odd.

Comment: I would recommend using `hasNext` instead of `toArray` because it avoids loading the entire result into RAM and building the array. If all we want is just to trigger execution, `toArray` is a bit over the top, isn't it?

Comment: @Christallkeks : Thankfully, if you have $out in the pipeline, it only [returns an empty cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate). There is no danger of loading the entire result into memory.

Comment: @Christallkeks I've edited my answer to include the comment about an empty cursor being returned, addressing your comment. Happy to delete our comments now, if you're happy with the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

Because the [`Aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) operation returns a cursor, not the results.
In order to return all the documents from the cursor, we need to use [`toArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) method.

Comment: It's unclear *why* the aggregation should return a cursor when the output is being written to another collection with $out; you'd have thought that that would happen automatically, without requiring any extra activity from the client.

Comment: @VinceBowdren That's interesting stuff and thanks for the info!